# "Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 6 : Password Locker"

Tags: macos, terminal, python-3.7

Good day. I am going through "Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 6 : Password Locker". I have typed the code exactly as given in the book such as(**I am using MAC OS**):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'JNAIBDUNOIH8937386SYB2G837DV37YD982DBS',
             'blog': 'VHUIDH782Y287S62W729SU29G17SGZ9HUih9hg',
             'luggage': '12345'}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password")
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] # first command line arg is the account name.

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print("Password for " + account + " copied to clipboard.")

else:
    print("There is no account named " + account)
```

However, when I run it from the terminal, I get an ERROR.
I typed this into the terminal:

```
chmod +x pw.py
./pw.py
```

And it works and gives me (as expected):

```
Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password
```

However, when I type in the word: *email or blog or luggage*, I get the **error** as follows:

```
zsh: command not found: email
```

Can someone please help me? I have struggling for days. Thank you.

Comment: The code works as expected on mac os, what is the output for `python -V`. Does it work with `python pw.py email`?

Comment: @MaartenDev I just tried that & it worked giving out what was expected. But when I run it with: chmod +x pw.py and afterwards ./pw.py, it still gives me the error: zsh: command not found: email

Comment: So it works with `python pw.py email` but fails with `./pw.py email`?

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out. I only typed `email`. Maybe that's why. When I now typed `python3 pw.py email`, it worked. I thought I only had to type in the 1 argument which was: email. So, now I have to type `python3 pw.py email` (3 arguments) and it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python scripts can be executed by prefixing the command with `python` or `python3`:

```
python pw.py email
```

or make the `pw.py` executable(`chmod +x pw.py`) and run it as script:

```
./pw.py email
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! I am completely new and started learning Terminal & running Python scripts from the Terminal a few days ago..